# Find probability of two events given certain information

Tags: probability, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

**Problem**

Given two events $A$ and $B$ such that $P(A \cup B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$ are known, find a formula for the probability of exactly one of these two events occurring.

**Attempt at a solution**

I interpret 'exactly one of these two events occcurring' as the event $C=A \setminus B$ or $D=B \setminus A$.

We have the following equalities $$(1) \space P(A)=P(A \setminus B) + P(A \cap B)$$ 
$$(2) \space P(B)=P(A \setminus B) + P(A \cap B)$$
$$(3) \space P(A \cup B)=P(B \setminus A)+P(A \cap B)+P(A \setminus B)$$

Since the hypothesis of the problem is that we only know the probability of the union and intersection, I am not so sure how could I derive a formula for $P(B \setminus A)$ and for $P(A \setminus B)$, I can't rely only on equality (3) since I would have one equation and two unknowns, but I don't have $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ as data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is asking for the probability of the event

$$E=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)=A\triangle B,$$

i.e. the probability that $A$ or $B$ occurs but not both.

We have

$$\Pr(E)=\Pr(A\cup B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$$

Comment: What is the slashy mean?

Comment: Set difference: $A\setminus B=\{x\in A\ |\ x\notin B\}$

Comment: As in everything left over in $A$ after removing the elements of $B$ from $A$? Doesn't this assume $B$ is contained in $A$? (which may not be true in this problem?)

Comment: No, it doesn't assume it's contained, just that there may be overlap.

Comment: (+1) It might help some readers to know that your last equation holds because $A\cup B$ is the disjoint union of $E$ and $A\cap B$, so $P(A\cup B) = P(E)+P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @ArukaJ $A\setminus B = A\cap B^\complement$ . It is the intersection of A and not-B.  That is all of A which does not overlap any of B.